# What is the best way to use Reactjs + webpack in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, reactjs, webpack

The recommended method to use React is to use it in a build pipeline which includes a package manager, a bundler, and a compiler as [suggested in official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html). Is it possible to do that in a WordPress plugin? If yes, what is the best method to do that?